# Render HTML code using ASP and NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asp-classic

I have this line:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
<tr>
<td><%= data[i].ginfo %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

but I'm getting that:

```
<a href='http://chriscoyier.net' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false;'>Solyc02g089120.2(intronic|unknown); </a>
```

instead of the `HTML` code. This code comes from an Express NodeJS server, here part of it:

```
app.post('/query', function(req, res) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM mutations";
  pool.query(query, function select(error, results, fields) {
      res.render('index.html',{data:results, error:null});
  });
});
```

How could I render that `HTML` code?

Comment: seems like you are pulling the information from the database, but isn't clear what you want

Comment: I'm not sure where you're coming from on this.  You can use JS as your server side scripting language in classic asp, but you need to use IIS to execute it, not the NodeJS server